# How to solve the integral $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\cos x \ln x}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to solve the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\cos x \ln x}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx$$

On wolfram-alpha I get the approximated value: -3.92203

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand $\cos$ into Taylor series around $0$, exchange the summation and integration, and integrate (once by parts to kill the $\ln$). The result is
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k)!(2k+\frac12)^2}=
-4\;{}_2F_3\left[\text{$\begin{array}{c}\frac14,\frac14 \\ 
\frac12,\frac54,\frac54\end{array}$};-\frac14\right]. $$

Comment: thx for the trick! but how to proof that the integration by parts works, i.e. the ln really is killed? and can I evaluate the sum analytically?

Comment: @Andy $\int_0^1 x^a\ln x\, dx=\int_0^1 \ln xd\frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}= -\frac{1}{a+1}\int_0^1 x^{a+1}d\ln x = -\frac{1}{(a+1)^2}$. Since the ratio of two consecutive terms in the sum is polynomial in $k$, the result can be expressed via hypergeometric series.

Answer (score 3):

Change the upper limit to $\infty$ instead of $1$, and get $I=-\sqrt{\dfrac\pi2}\cdot\bigg(\gamma+\dfrac\pi2+2\ln2\bigg)$. This is easily shown by combining [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) with the expression of the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) and then [differentiating under the integral sign](http://fy.chalmers.se/~tfkhj/FeynmanIntegration.pdf). However, the integral currently posted does not possess a nice form, unless one is willing to consider hypergeometric series and/or incomplete $\Gamma$ functions as such.